# Using config/secrets.yml in Rails 4.0.2 version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, configuration-files

I was reading http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html
and saw there the trick with `config/secrets.yml`

I moved my secret_base_keys to that file, and removed `secret_token.rb` file.

But server doesn't start.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You didn't set config.secret_key_base. Read the upgrade documentation to learn more about this new config option. (called from service at /home/bismailov/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138)
[2014-01-15 16:15:51] ERROR RuntimeError: You must set config.secret_key_base in your app's config.
```

I believe that is because I don't use Rails 4.1 yet.

Is there any way to implement this new functionality (secrets.yml) in Rails version 4.0? Maybe some kind of gem...

Thank you very much!

Comment: run rake secrets and then start server as mentioned in above link.

Comment: I tryed `rake secrets` there is none. But `rake secret` works, I generated two secret tokens for using in secrets.yml

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This `secret_key_base` deprecation does not seem to have alternative syntax to remove the deprecation warning in a Rails 4.0 application. To satisfy the deprecation, follow the steps for moving the production key to `secrets.yml` and delete the `secret_token.rb` file. The implement a YAML loader in your `application.rb` to extract the token from your `secrets.yml` file.

Use `rake secret` to generate a new token for each of your environments. Copy and paste the output to each section of your `secrets.yml` file.

```
# config/secrets.yml
development:
  secret_key_base: __pasted from rake secret___
test:
  secret_key_base: __pasted from rake secret___
production:
  secret_key_base: __pasted token from config/initializers/secret_token.rb___


# config/application.rb
# TODO Remove this in Rails 4.1
config.secret_key_base = YAML.load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/secrets.yml"))[Rails.env]['secret_key_base']
```

Cite: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13298

UPDATE:

My original post focused on Inspired by @user2998870, I added a method to my `application.rb` that is allows one to implement multiple secrets, not just `secret_key_base`. This makes top-level keys accessible as methods e.g. `Rails.application.secrets.braintree_merchant_id`.

If nested, one can call the nested key value using `Rails.application.secrets.braintree['merchant_key']`.

Note: The original code above is still needed for `secret_key_base` to operate correctly in Rails 4.0.

```
# config/application.rb
def secrets
  @secrets ||= begin
    yaml = YAML.load(File.open("#{Rails.root}/config/secrets.yml"))[Rails.env]
    ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new.merge!(yaml.symbolize_keys)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

`config/secrets.yml` is a feature of Rails 4.1. Upgrade to Rails 4.1 to use the feature.

Answer (score 1):

I did like @scarver2 mentioned, but I did it by borrowing some code from Rails 4.1 (I'm currently using on 4.0.3)

```
# Load 3rd party service passwords from config/services.rb.
# This is patch code to support config/services.rb till we upgrade to Rails 4.1.
# TODO: Remove this section after upgrading to Rails 4.1.

# Borrowed from rails/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb
config.paths.add "config/secrets", with: "config/secrets.yml"

# Borrowed from rails/railties/lib/rails/application.rb
def secrets #:nodoc:
  @secrets ||= begin
    secrets = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
    yaml = config.paths["config/secrets"].first
    if File.exist?(yaml)
      require "erb"
      all_secrets = YAML.load(ERB.new(IO.read(yaml)).result) || {}
      env_secrets = all_secrets[Rails.env]
      secrets.merge!(env_secrets.symbolize_keys) if env_secrets
    end

    # Fallback to config.secret_key_base if secrets.secret_key_base isn't set
    secrets.secret_key_base ||= config.secret_key_base

    secrets
  end
end
```